# How to create a library that can have individual components imported if required à la lodash

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I've written a library in es6 using import/export. I can bundle this library using Rollup into a IIFE that can be used in the browser.

I also want to be able to use this library in other projects. However, I won't usually want to include the whole library, only parts of it.

Because the library is written using es6 import/export I can include the unbundled index.js file as a dependency in another project and then `import { myFunc } from 'my-lib'` and this works great - I only get myFunc when my project is bundled.

However, I ran into an issue because these files haven't been processed by babel and therefore contain es6 code such as arrow functions. I have read that if you're going to publish a library it shouldn't need to be transpiled by the end-user.

How can I take my es6 library and bundle it in such a way that it is transpiled, but also able to have its individual components imported? I want a similar situation to how lodash is organised.

This isn't the easiest thing to articulate so if anything isn't clear please leave a comment and I'll edit my question to try and clarify.

Comment: "*I have read that if you're going to publish a library it shouldn't need to be transpiled by the end user.*" - where did you read that? It's not necessarily true. The easiest would be to distribute two versions, one for people who use their own bundler/transpiler and want to benefit from tree shaking, and one that is a ready-to use ES5 version with all features.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it is best to use webpack to create 2 modules.  One for web and one for node.

In your node build, you can choose to transpile, or simply keep the code in ES6, letting the library client decide.

Your web build can tree-shake and remove unused code.

Your webpack will export an array instead of an object.

Here is the official webpack snippet (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/)

```
const path = require('path');
const serverConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'lib.node.js'
  }
  //…
};

const clientConfig = {
  target: 'web', // <=== can be omitted as default is 'web'
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'lib.js'
  }
  //…
};

module.exports = [ serverConfig, clientConfig ];
```

Comment: "*Here is the official webpack snippet*" - could you link where you found that, please?

Comment: No, you are told to do both: provide the relevant information, as well as a link for the source and further details